# I want threads to print natural number periodically in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm new to multi-threading, I want to achieve something like below using C#.

```
Thread 0 printed 0
Thread 1 printed 1
Thread 2 printed 2
Thread 3 printed 3
Thread 4 printed 4
Thread 5 printed 5
Thread 6 printed 6
Thread 7 printed 7
Thread 8 printed 8
Thread 9 printed 9
Thread 0 printed 10
Thread 1 printed 11
Thread 2 printed 12
Thread 3 printed 13
Thread 4 printed 14
Thread 5 printed 15
Thread 6 printed 16
Thread 7 printed 17
Thread 8 printed 18
Thread 9 printed 19
.
.
.
Thread 10 printed 99.
```

I have done something like this but of course, requirement is beyond.

```
 class Program
{
    static int count = 0; // the shared counter from 1 to 100 
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];   // i have created 10 threads each one will print 10 cyclic values 
        string result = "";
        int cc = 0;
        while (cc!=10) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(printTill10));
            tr[i].Start();
            tr[i].Join();


        }
            cc++;
        }

    }

    string s = "";
    static void printTill10()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(++count+ "Printed by thread  #"+ 
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);



    }
}
```

I am confused either I should use a lock or something like monitor.wait or monitor.pulse etc.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you really want to impose the order in which each thread is being executed (like thread A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D), or is only the sequential increment of the counter relevant (like print 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)? If it is the former, then this is not really about multi-threading but about chaining tasks...

Comment: @elgonzo, I want to do it using multi-threading concepts. Like T1 prints 1 so it will print 11 and if T2 print 2 then it will print 12 in next cycle. And this chain will continue till 100, in a way that each thread will print exactly 10 counts. I know this will happen using wait and pulse but I am unable to map it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like so:

First declare a variable `count` in the class so that it can be accessed by all threads. Also, create an object `locker` that will allow us to lock the `count` variable.

```
static int count;
static object locker;
```

Then, create the method that contains the code that the threads will all run:

```
static void printTill10()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (count < 100)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread {0} printed {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(), count.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does when run is the following:

1. Enters a `while` loop which loops forever.
2. Locks `locker` to make sure only one operation is being performed on `count`  at a time.
3. Checks to see if `count` is under 100.
4. Increases `count` by one.
5. Prints a string exactly like the one you're trying to get (I used `String.Format` instead of concentration because its neater)

Simple right? This is the code that our threads will run. Now we can focus on the multithreading part.

```
static void Main()
{
    count = 0; // Be sure to give count an initial value to prevent an exception from being thrown.
    locker = new object();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => printTill100());
        threads[i].Start();
    } 

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Our `Main` does the following:

1. Gives an initial value to the `count` and `locker` variables.
2. Creates an array to put our threads in.
3. Enters a for loop which populates the array with threads and starts them.
4. Makes the main thread (the one code runs in by default) wait forever (specified by `Timeout.Infinite`. This last bit is an important one. By default, all code runs in a single thread called the *main* thread. If we don't tell it to wait, it will exit after the loop is done, closing the program. It will not wait until our other threads are finished.

Comment: Really thanks for this detailed explanation, though its not working as I am expecting but I gotta know many things from this.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one thing you have missed while writing code in

> printTill10()

method.

Just put one lock block in printTill10() method like this.

static void printTill10()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(++count + "Printed by thread  #" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        }

and also declare locker object in the Pragram class like

> static readonly object _locker = new object();

Here is the complete code

```
class Program
    {
        static int count = 0; // the shared counter from 1 to 100 
        static readonly object _locker = new object();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];   // i have created 10 threads each one will print 10 cyclic values 
            string result = "";
            int cc = 0;
            while (cc != 10)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {

                    tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(printTill10));
                    tr[i].Start();
                    tr[i].Join();


                }
                cc++;
            }

        }

        string s = "";
        static void printTill10()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(++count + "Printed by thread  #" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        }
    }
```

It will work as per your requirement. :)

Comment: That's not really practical multi-threading. This is sequential processing. Not sure what the point of your answer is...

Comment: Thanks to considering, though it needs bit correction.

Answer (score 0):

After a continuous try, I got to complete the requirements of my task. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class EntryPoint
{
    static private int counter = 0;
    static private object theLock = new Object();
    static object obj = new object();
    static private void count()
    {
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                lock (theLock)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count {0} Thread{1}",
                    counter++, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
                     if (counter>=10) 
                    Monitor.Pulse(theLock);
                    Monitor.Wait(theLock);  }  }}
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(count));
            tr[i].Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Monitor maintains a ready queue in a sequential order hence I achieved what I wanted:

[image]